# Numpy converting range of angles from (-Pi, Pi) to (0, 2*Pi)

Tags: python, numpy

This seems like it would be very straight forward but I can't seem to figure out how to map angles between -Pi and Pi to the range 0 to 2Pi.  I tried using np.select but it freezes my program for some reason.  I need the angles in this range since they will be used as training data for a neural net which can not output negative numbers.

```
audio = wav.read('/home/chase/Desktop/ge.wav')[1].astype(np.float32)
audio = np.mean(audio, 1)
audio /= np.max(np.abs(audio))
audio = np.array([np.fft.rfft(audio[i:i + FRAME_SIZE]) for i in range(0, len(audio) - len(audio) % FRAME_SIZE, FRAME_SIZE)])
audio /= FRAME_SIZE
audio_mag = np.abs(audio)
audio_phase = np.angle(audio)

#this line freezes the program
audio_phase = np.select(audio_phase < 0 , 2 * np.pi + audio_phase, audio_phase)
```

I need the audio

Comment: Did you try `np.where`?

Comment: Thanks that works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let us say you have these angles:

```
>>> angles = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10)
>>> angles
array([-3.14159265, -2.44346095, -1.74532925, -1.04719755, -0.34906585,
    0.34906585,  1.04719755,  1.74532925,  2.44346095,  3.14159265])
```

There are two possible ways of doing this ...

1. Use `numpy` expressions for finding the negative values ...

The ones less than zero should be converted to the right value. Something like this:

```
>>> (2*np.pi + angles) * (angles < 0) + angles*(angles > 0)
array([ 3.14159265,  3.83972435,  4.53785606,  5.23598776,  5.93411946,
    0.34906585,  1.04719755,  1.74532925,  2.44346095,  3.14159265])
```

Remember that in numpy, you can do logical tests ... `angles < 0` is a boolean array. However, `1*(angles < 0)` is a numeric array, where `True` values are mapped to `1` and `False` values are mapped to `0`. You can combine the two concepts to get your answer.

2. You can simply recognize that this is a mathematical expression you are trying to solve:

So for that, simply add `2*np.pi` to everything and take the mod. This is exactly like finding the "units place", or converting a number into an octal number etc ...

```
>>> (angles + 2 * np.pi) % (2 * np.pi)
array([ 3.14159265,  3.83972435,  4.53785606,  5.23598776,  5.93411946,
    0.34906585,  1.04719755,  1.74532925,  2.44346095,  3.14159265])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In the first solution: What about the case `angles == 0`? Maybe replace with `(2*np.pi + angles) * (angles < 0) + angles*(angles >= 0)` ?

Answer (score 18):

Here are several different methods complete with timing:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np; from numpy import linspace, pi

In [2]: N=10000

In [3]: %timeit x=linspace(-pi, pi, N); np.where(x<0 , 2*pi+x, x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.1 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit x=linspace(-pi, pi, N); np.select(x<0 , 2*pi+x, x)
1 loops, best of 3: 354 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit x=linspace(-pi, pi, N); x[x<0] += 2*pi
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.5 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit x=linspace(-pi, pi, N); (x + 2*pi)*(x<0) + x*(x>=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit x=linspace(-pi, pi, N); (x + 2*pi)%(2*pi)
10000 loops, best of 3: 192 µs per loop
```

I find `x[x<0] += 2*pi` the most readable, but `where(x<0, x+2*pi, x)` is slightly faster. The `select` form is by far the slowest.

For comparison, here is the plain linspace function on the same machine:

```
In [8]: %timeit x=linspace(-pi, pi, N)
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.9 µs per loop
```

Given that the program is failing on the select and not the far more expensive fft function, you may be running into a low memory condition, with the array paging to disk (both `x<0` and `2*pi+x` generate arrays, plus you have the original `x` and the return value created by `select`).  If this is the case, then you may be better off correcting phase frame by frame.

Comment: +1 for the comparison and timings! `x[x<0] += 2 * np.pi` would be my option, not just for readability, but because it does an inplace modifications to the array, quite useful if `x` is very large.

Answer (score 8):

Angles between -Pi and +Pi:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> angles = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10)
```

Shift to 0 to 2*Pi:

```
>>> angles_2pi = np.mod(angles, 2*np.pi)
>>> angles_2pi
array([3.14159265, 3.83972435, 4.53785606, 5.23598776, 5.93411946,
   0.34906585, 1.04719755, 1.74532925, 2.44346095, 3.14159265])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this worked for wrapping and angle between [0-2pi] by using part of Neapolitan's answer above.

```
import numpy as np
def wrap(angle):
    tmp = np.arctan2(np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle))
    return float(np.where(tmp<0 , 2*np.pi+tmp, tmp))
```

Some of the other methods had issues when the angles went above double of 2 pi.

Answer (score -1):

You can try use the function `map` with `lambda`

```
>>>angles = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10)
array([-3.14159265, -2.44346095, -1.74532925, -1.04719755, -0.34906585,
        0.34906585,  1.04719755,  1.74532925,  2.44346095,  3.14159265])

>>>map(lambda x: x if x > 0 else x + 2*np.pi, angles)

[3.1415926535897931, 3.839724354387525, 4.5378560551852569, 5.2359877559829879, 5.9341194567807207, 0.34906585039886595, 1.0471975511965974, 1.7453292519943293, 2.4434609527920612, 3.1415926535897931]
```